# Navigate to async route from API on page load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm loading my routes through an API. This works just fine as long as you're starting the page from root `#/`, and I can load pages through `<router-link>` just fine (i.e. `#/SomeSubPage`).

The problems appears when trying to go to `#/SomeSubPage` directly (permalink to http://mysite/#SomeSubPage), or when clicking refresh in the browser when you're on the route.

I understand that this is because the routes are loaded from API, which means they are not available on the initial page load, so `vue-router` doesn't yet know about them.

An example of how the routes are added is:

```
fetch('http://mysite/api/routes').then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(myRoutes) {
       myRoutes.forEach(function(myRoute) {
           router.addRoutes([{
               path: myRoute.path,
               component: () => import('somecomponent.vue')
           }]);
       });
    });
```

Seing as this is loaded async and not loaded until after the route is first initialized, any request to `#/SomeSubPage` are not caught because the route definition is not yet ready.

Is there a way to make `vue-router` refresh itself when a new route has been added, so that you can go to `#/SomeSubPage` and have it work on the first try?

Comment: You could have it check that the routes have been loaded in a beforeEach function in your router and then load the routes before the route is executed if necessary. Another thought: are you using history mode for your router? The behavior sounds like it might be the issue with going straight to a route in history mode: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations.

Comment: I'm not using history mode (hence the hashbangs). Could you maybe give an example of what your suggestion so that I get a rougher idea on what I need to do?

Comment: hi Check api/routes return list .it it successfully return check myRoute.path field in the list